# What are the odds for a random collection of numbers to have sum less than a certain number?

Tags: probability-distributions, computational-complexity, recurrences

Let's say we have $I$ collections of numbers, $N_i$ numbers in each. A collection may contain repeating numbers. We randomly take one number from each collection. What is the probability for a sum of these selected numbers to be less than some number $T$? EDIT: you can assume that all numbers are positive integers.

I managed to get the recurrence relation for $s_j^i$ - the number of ways to get a certain number $j$ as a sum of the first $i$ random numbers. Let's say we have a collection of possible sums before $i$, which is described by $s_x^{i-1}$. For each number in the current collection $n_i^k$, we need to add $j-n_i^k$ in order to get $j$ as a sum. So there are a total of $s_{j-n_i^k}^{i-1}$ ways to get this sum via number $n_i^k$. If we take into account all numbers of the current collection, it turns into: $$\sum_{k=1}^{N_i}s_{j-n_i^k}^{i-1}$$

To get the desired probability, we divide the sum of suitable cases by the number of all possible cases: $$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{T}s_k^I}{\prod_{i=0}^{I}N_i}$$

[Here's a board with relevant formulas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcjAU.jpg)

These formulas were derived from my DP code:

```
s = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
s[-1][0] = 1
for i in range(len(n_groups)):
    for n in n_groups[i]:
        for prev_sum in s[i - 1]:
            s[i][n + prev_sum] += s[i - 1][prev_sum]

less = 0
last_array = s[-1]
for _sum in last_array:
    if _sum < N:
        less += last_array[_sum]

print(less / math.prod([len(n_group) for n_group in n_groups]))
```

Time and space complexity grow exponentially with growth of the number of initial collections. I wonder if there is a better (perhaps non concurrent) formula for this probability and therefore, a faster algorithm.

Comment: I'm guessing that by "number" you mean *positive integer*, since the number of ways to get a certain (real) number $j$ as a sum of the first $i$ random (real) numbers is generally zero. But the whole question seems impossible, as there's no indication of what properties your initial collections of numbers may have. E.g., if you don't know how big the numbers in those collections are, how can you hope to say anything about a sum of numbers taken from them being less that some other given number?

Comment: @GerryMyerson my solution uses the fact that all numbers are positive integers indeed, but in general we don't need to know the number of ways to get a **certain** number, we are only interested in how many of those sums will be **smaller** than a certain number. I don't understand your second concern, can you clarify please?

Comment: I quote from the question: "$p_j^i$ – the number of ways to get a certain number $j$ as a sum of the first $i$ random numbers." The second concern: the probability for a sum of the selected numbers to be less than, say, $17I$ is one if all the numbers in the collections are less than $17$, and zero if all the numbers in the collections are greater than $17$, so you can't say anything about the probability the sum is less than $17I$ if you don't know anything about the numbers in the collections.

Comment: And I think you should edit the question to make it explicit that all your numbers are positive integers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson we know what the numbers are, of course: "For each number in the current collection $n_i^k$ ...".

Comment: And I still think you should edit the question to make it explicit that all your numbers are positive integers.

Comment: This resembles the knapsack problem, so I doubt there's a polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: @GerryMyerson done.

Comment: What is a random positive integer, though? AFAIK there is no uniform distribution on this set.

Comment: @MaxHorn there is a predetermined set of collections of numbers (see the picture) and we randomly pick a number from each collection. "Randomly" in this case means that each number of the collection has the same probability (1 / collection size) to be picked.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your quest; I thought you wanted an answer independent of the specific sets, but that's not what you meant

Answer (score 2):

Consider $I$ collections consisting of 2 elements each: $n_i$ and $0$. Let's say we managed to find desired probability in polynomial time for number $T$, which corresponds to the number of ways to get a sum equal to $T$ by combining numbers from our collections ($a_T = p_T * 2^I$). Let's find it for $T-1$ too. Now we can get the number of combinations with the sum equal to $T$: $a_T - a_{T-1} = (p_T - p_{T-1}) * 2^I$. So we just solved the knapsack problem in polynomial time. Since there are no known P-complete solutions to this problem, our solution is not P-complete either.

However, I'd appreciate some ideas for approximate algorithms.

Credit to Matt F. for noticing resemblance with the knapsack problem and to Пчел for coming up with this solution.